# Convert from string to float

Tags: c, casting

I am trying to convert a variable from string to float. But I'm getting wrong values. Below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char endTime[4][26];
    time_t timere;
    struct tm *tm_infoe;
    float dlay[4][3];
    time(&timere);
    tm_infoe = localtime(&timere);
    strftime(endTime[1], 26, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", tm_infoe);
    printf("Endtime %s\n", endTime[1]);
    dlay[1][1]=atol(endTime[1]);
    printf("Value from atol:%ld\n", atol(endTime[1]));
    dlay[1][1]=atof(endTime[1]);
    printf("Float value from atof:%f\n", dlay[1][1]);
    sscanf(endTime[1], "%f", &dlay[1][1]);
    printf("Float value from sscanf:%f\n", dlay[1][1]);
}
```

Both the functions atof and sscanf are giving wrong values. Below is the output. Can you please tell me where is the mistake?

```
Endtime 20151018221710
Value from atol:20151018221710
Float value from atof:20151017668608.000000
Float value from sscanf:20151017668608.000000
```

atol is giving correct value, but I need it in float format.

Comment: How it is wrong? It won't get better.

Comment: `float` is accurate to 7-8 decimal digits. Looks like you observe results within this tolerance. What again seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `double` here instead of `float` .While you use `float` many numbers can go slight change . Therefore , you get such value , not wrong though .

Here a simple example using `double` -

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
   char s[]="20151018221710";       // your string 
   double a;                        // declare a as double
   sscanf(s,"%lf",&a);              // use %lf specifier for double
   printf("%f",a);                  //print value of a 
   return 0;
}
```

Output -

`20151018221710.000000`

[Demo here](https://ideone.com/c5reyF)

Comment: Thank you, changing from float data type to double data type resolved the issue. Thanks for the quick response.